# AllowDrop=false not working WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I set AllowDrop only to the leaf node and AllowDrop=false to others but After setting AllowDrop = false it is still allowing Drop option.

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvParameters" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:MyTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                <Grid >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}" x:Name="tbFullParameter" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" AllowDrop="{Binding Path=AllowDrop}"  x:Name="tbParameter" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="tbParameter_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="tbParameter_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Did you tried to set it manually without binding? You sure the binding is working?

Comment: Yes. i checked the binded values in the live propertywindow. it is false. Even if i hardcode it as false also it is allowing drag option.

Comment: do you have call OnPropertyChanged on AllowDrop ?

Comment: No, Dont have it

Comment: @Nathiya, You have to notifies clients that a property value has changed.

Comment: @Nathiya, read more at : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged